# CR2 raw image file parser in Python 3

Tags: python, parsing, python-3.x, image, file-structure

I haven't used Python in a number of years, but recently started working on a project called [Photoshell](https://github.com/campaul/ph.sh) which is written in Python 3.

As I attempted to learn the "Pythonic way", I wrote a [parser](https://github.com/campaul/ph.sh/pull/68) for Canon's CR2 raw image file format. I'm not sure how "pythonic" the parser is, so I'd love to get some feedback on how it could be improved that way. Also how the speed / caching could be improved when handling large binary blobs (extracted images, in this case). Finaly, I suspect that the file read/writing could also use some work.

```
import os
import struct

tags = {
    'image_width': 0x0100,
    'image_length': 0x0101,
    'bits_per_sample': 0x0102,
    'compression': 0x0103,
    'make': 0x010f,
    'model': 0x0110,
    'strip_offset': 0x0111,
    'orientation': 0x0112,
    'strip_byte_counts': 0x0117,
    'x_resolution': 0x011a,
    'y_resolution': 0x011b,
    'resolution_unit': 0x0128,
    'datetime': 0x0132,
    'exif': 0x8769,
    'gps_data': 0x8825
}

# Mapping of tag types to format strings.
# Format strings that start with a * are too long to fit in the IFD entry and
# are actually a pointer to somewhere else in the file.
tag_types = {
    0x1: 'B',  # Unsigned char
    0x2: '*s',  # String (with ending 0)
    0x3: 'H',  # Unsigned short
    0x4: 'L',  # Unsigned long
    0x5: '*Q',  # Unsigned rational
    0x6: 'b',  # Signed char
    0x7: '*p',  # Byte sequence
    0x8: 'h',  # Signed short
    0x9: 'l',  # Signed long
    0xA: '*q',  # Signed rational
    0xB: '*f',  # Float (IEEE)
    0xC: '*d',  # Double (IEEE)
}

# Format info: http://lclevy.free.fr/cr2/
# The Cr2 class loads a CR2 file from disk. It is currently read-only.


class Cr2(object):

    class Header(object):

        def __init__(self, fhandle):
            assert not fhandle.closed
            fhandle.seek(0)
            header_buffer = fhandle.read(16)
            (endianness,) = struct.unpack_from('H', header_buffer)
            if endianness == 0x4949:
                # Intel
                self.endian_flag = '<'
            elif endianness == 0x4D4D:
                # Motorola
                self.endian_flag = '>'
            else:
                # WTF (use native)?
                self.endian_flag = '@'
            raw_header = struct.unpack_from(self.endian_flag + 'HHLHBBL',
                                            header_buffer)
            self.raw_header = raw_header
            self.tiff_magic_word = raw_header[1]
            self.tiff_offset = raw_header[2]
            self.magic_word = raw_header[3]
            self.major_version = raw_header[4]
            self.minor_version = raw_header[5]
            self.raw_ifd_offset = raw_header[6]

    class Ifd(object):

        class IfdEntry(object):

            def __init__(self, num, parent):
                assert not parent.fhandle.closed

                self.parent = parent
                parent.fhandle.seek(parent.offset + 2 + (12 * num))
                buf = parent.fhandle.read(8)
                (self.tag_id, self.tag_type, self.value_len) = struct.unpack_from(
                    parent.endian_flag + 'HHL', buf)
                buf = parent.fhandle.read(4)
                if tag_types[self.tag_type][0] == '*':
                    (self.raw_value,) = struct.unpack_from(parent.endian_flag +
                                                           'L', buf)
                    self.value = -1
                else:
                    (self.raw_value,) = struct.unpack_from(parent.endian_flag +
                                                           tag_types[self.tag_type], buf)
                    self.value = self.raw_value

            def get_value(self):
                # If value is not cached yet, read it
                if self.value == -1:
                    # Read value from file
                    self.parent.fhandle.seek(self.raw_value)
                    buf = self.parent.fhandle.read(self.value_len)
                    tag_fmt = tag_types[self.tag_type][1:]
                    if tag_fmt == 's' or tag_fmt == 'p':
                        tag_fmt = repr(self.value_len) + tag_fmt
                    (self.value,) = struct.unpack_from(
                        self.parent.endian_flag + tag_fmt, buf)
                    if tag_fmt[-1] == 's':
                        self.value = self.value.decode("utf-8")[:-1]
                return self.value

        def __init__(self, offset, parent):
            assert not parent.fhandle.closed

            self.fhandle = parent.fhandle
            self.offset = offset
            self.endian_flag = parent.get_endian_flag()

            # Read num entries
            parent.fhandle.seek(offset)
            buf = parent.fhandle.read(2)
            (self.num_entries,) = struct.unpack_from(
                parent.get_endian_flag() + 'H', buf)

            # Read next offset
            parent.fhandle.seek(offset + (2 + 12 * self.num_entries))
            buf = parent.fhandle.read(2)
            (self.next_ifd_offset,) = struct.unpack_from(
                parent.get_endian_flag() + 'H', buf)

        def find_entry(self, name):
            for entry_num in range(0, self.num_entries):
                ifd_entry = self.IfdEntry(entry_num, self)

                if ifd_entry.tag_id == tags[name]:
                    return ifd_entry
            return -1

    def __init__(self, file_path):
        self.file_path = file_path
        self.fhandle = open(file_path, "rb")
        self.header = self.Header(self.fhandle)
        self.ifd = []
        self.ifd.append(self.Ifd(16, self))
        for i in range(1, 3):
            self.ifd.append(self.Ifd(self.ifd[i - 1].next_ifd_offset, self))

    def __enter__(self):
        return self

    def __exit__(self, type, value, traceback):
        self.fhandle.close()

    def get_endian_flag(self):
        return self.header.endian_flag

    def get_header(self):
        return self.header
```

Comment: Latest code moved to [here](https://github.com/photoshell/rawphoto).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The comment

```
# Format info: http://lclevy.free.fr/cr2/
# The Cr2 class loads a CR2 file from disk. It is currently read-only.
```

would be better in `Cr2`'s docstring. "It is currently read-only" doesn't mean much since everything is public. To mark things "private" the convention is to prefix them with underscores (eg. `self._header`).

I wouldn't do that, though; I'd get rid of the getters and just have attributes. If you really want getters in order to make things read-only, use properties.

Since you're requiring Python 3, remove `(object)` from the inheritance list; it was only required while transitioning from 2.x.

I would separate the embedded classes; sticking them together seems relatively pointless.

IMHO, `[endianness] = ...` is nicer than `(endianness,) = ...`. Feel free to ignore this point.

I personally don't think `Header` should be calling `seek` on the input file; it should trust the user to give it an appropriately seeked file, even if that may be offset.

Your `assert not fhandle.closed` isn't needed; `read` will error just fine if it's closed (with a more descriptive error, too).

It doesn't seem like `Header` needs `fhandle` at all, actually; it should be able to receive just a string. FWIW, `header_buffer` isn't a buffer.

I would use a dictionary to calculate `endian_flag`.

```
endian_flags = {
    0x4949: '<', # Intel
    0x4D4D: '>', # Motorola
}

# Default to native
endian_flag = endian_flags.get(endianness, "@")
```

`Header` looks like it could be a `namedtuple`.

You use `unpack_from` a lot where `unpack` alone should work. Prefer the later.

This all gives:

```
from collections import namedtuple

# Mapping from manufacturer to associated endianness as accepted by struct
endian_flags = {
    0x4949: '<', # Intel
    0x4D4D: '>', # Motorola
}

_HeaderFields = namedtuple("HeaderFields", [
    "endian_flag", "raw_header", "tiff_magic_word", "tiff_offset",
    "magic_word", "major_version", "minor_version", "raw_ifd_offset"
])

class Header(_HeaderFields):
    __slots__ = ()

    def __new__(cls, header_bytes):
        [endianness] = struct.unpack_from('H', header_bytes)

        # Default to native
        endian_flag = endian_flags.get(endianness, "@")
        raw_header = struct.unpack(endian_flag + 'HHLHBBL', header_bytes)

        return super().__new__(cls, endian_flag, raw_header, *raw_header[1:])
```

In `IfdEntry`, you have

```
tag_types[self.tag_type][0] == '*'
```

which would be more clear as

```
tag_types[self.tag_type].startswith('*')
```

In `get_value` you do

```
tag_fmt = tag_types[self.tag_type][1:]
```

but I don't see a reason to use a slice. In fact, I would do the even stricter

```
_, tag_fmt = tag_types[self.tag_type]
```

`get_value` would be better as a property.

I would change `self.tag_type` to be the result from after translating with `tag_types`.

I would do a single read from `fhandle` in `__init__` and use `unpack_from`'s `offset` parameter to read parts. This emphasised how repetitive the unpacking is, so I'd make a local function to reduce the repetition:

```
def __init__(self, num, parent):
    self.parent = parent
    parent.fhandle.seek(parent.offset + 2 + (12 * num))
    entry_bytes = parent.fhandle.read(12)

    def unpack_at(type, offset):
        return struct.unpack_from(parent.endian_flag + type, entry_bytes, offset)

    self.tag_id, tag_type, self.value_len = unpack_at('HHL', 0)
    self.tag_type = tag_types[tag_type]

    if self.tag_type.startswith('*'):
        [self.raw_value] = unpack_at('L', 8)
        self._value = -1
    else:
        [self.raw_value] = unpack_at(self.tag_type, 8)
        self._value = self.raw_value
```

Use `None` instead of `-1` as a "missing value" sentinel; that's what it's for, after all.

Looking further, I got confused as to why you delayed it anyway; `value_len` never seems to be big so it makes sense just to do it eagerly. This pointed out what seems to be a bug: `self.parent.fhandle.read(self.value_len)` is too few bytes when `tag_fmt` represents a value of > 1 bytes. This kind of error and repetition suggests that you should really have a class to encapsulate reading data from the file. `Cr2` would work great for that.

You also don't check for insufficient read sizes, but I'll let that be for now.

Being non-lazy, you could make `IfdEntry` another immutable `namedtuple`:

```
_IfdEntryFields = namedtuple("IfdEntryFields", [
    "image", "tag_id", "tag_type", "value_len", "raw_value", "value"
])

class IfdEntry(_IfdEntryFields):
    __slots__ = ()

    def __new__(cls, offset, image):
        tag_id, tag_type_key, value_len = image.read_at('HHL', offset)
        tag_type = tag_types[tag_type_key]

        if tag_type.startswith('*'):
            _, tag_type = tag_type

            [raw_value] = image.read_at('L', offset + 8)
            [value] = image.read_at('{}{}'.format(value_len, tag_type), raw_value)

            if tag_type == "s":
                value = value.rstrip(b'\0').decode("utf-8")

        else:
            [raw_value] = image.read_at(tag_type, offset + 8)
            value = raw_value

        return super().__new__(cls, image, tag_id, tag_type, value_len, raw_value, value)
```

The same goes for `Ifd`:

```
_IfdFields = namedtuple("IfdFields", [
    "image", "offset", "num_entries", "next_ifd_offset"
])

class Ifd(_IfdFields):
    __slots__ = ()

    def __new__(cls, offset, image):
        [num_entries] = image.read_at('H', offset)
        [next_ifd_offset] = image.read_at('H', offset + (2 + 12 * num_entries))
        return super().__new__(cls, image, offset, num_entries, next_ifd_offset)
```

`find_entry` should just iterate over `range(self.num_entries)`; the `0` is optional.

You probably shouldn't return `-1` on failure; I suggest `None` as before.

In `Cr2`, you have `self.ifd`. It makes sense to call this `self.ifds`. I would also do the loop as:

```
self.ifds = [Idf(16, self)]
for i in range(3):
    self.ifds.append(Ifd(self.ifds[-1].next_ifd_offset, self))
```

You should be more careful about how you handle errors in `self.__init__`; if the constructor closes the file should also be left closed.

Your first read to find the endianness uses the default, platform-specific endianness. I would imagine you want a more sensible default like `'>'`.

`Ifd` remakes its entries every call to `find_entry`. It makes more sense IMHO to generate once on creation.

All in all, I get something like

```
from collections import namedtuple
from struct import Struct

tags = {
    'image_width': 0x0100,
    'image_length': 0x0101,
    'bits_per_sample': 0x0102,
    'compression': 0x0103,
    'make': 0x010f,
    'model': 0x0110,
    'strip_offset': 0x0111,
    'orientation': 0x0112,
    'strip_byte_counts': 0x0117,
    'x_resolution': 0x011a,
    'y_resolution': 0x011b,
    'resolution_unit': 0x0128,
    'datetime': 0x0132,
    'exif': 0x8769,
    'gps_data': 0x8825
}

# Mapping of tag types to format strings.
# Format strings that start with a * are too long to fit in the IFD entry and
# are actually a pointer to somewhere else in the file.
tag_types = {
    0x1: 'B',  # Unsigned char
    0x2: '*s',  # String (with ending 0)
    0x3: 'H',  # Unsigned short
    0x4: 'L',  # Unsigned long
    0x5: '*Q',  # Unsigned rational
    0x6: 'b',  # Signed char
    0x7: '*p',  # Byte sequence
    0x8: 'h',  # Signed short
    0x9: 'l',  # Signed long
    0xA: '*q',  # Signed rational
    0xB: '*f',  # Float (IEEE)
    0xC: '*d',  # Double (IEEE)
}

# Mapping from manufacturer to associated endianness as accepted by struct
endian_flags = {
    0x4949: '<', # Intel
    0x4D4D: '>', # Motorola
}


_HeaderFields = namedtuple("HeaderFields", [
    "endian_flag", "raw_header", "tiff_magic_word", "tiff_offset", "magic_word",
    "major_version", "minor_version", "raw_ifd_offset"
])

class Header(_HeaderFields):
    __slots__ = ()

    def __new__(cls, image):
        # Default to native
        [endian_flag_key] = image.read_at('H', 0, endian_flag='>')
        endian_flag = endian_flags[endian_flag_key]

        raw_header = image.read_at('HHLHBBL', 0, endian_flag=endian_flag)
        return super().__new__(cls, endian_flag, raw_header, *raw_header[1:])


_IfdEntryFields = namedtuple("IfdEntryFields", ["tag_id", "tag_type", "value"])

class IfdEntry(_IfdEntryFields):
    __slots__ = ()

    def __new__(cls, offset, image):
        tag_id, tag_type_key, value_len = image.read_at('HHL', offset)
        tag_type = tag_types[tag_type_key]

        if tag_type.startswith('*'):
            _, tag_type = tag_type

            [pointer] = image.read_at('L', offset + 8)
            [value] = image.read_at(str(value_len) + tag_type, pointer)

            if tag_type == "s":
                value = value.rstrip(b'\0').decode("utf-8")

        else:
            [value] = image.read_at(tag_type, offset + 8)

        return super().__new__(cls, tag_id, tag_type, value)


_IfdFields = namedtuple("IfdFields", ["image", "entries", "offset", "num_entries", "next_ifd_offset"])

class Ifd(_IfdFields):
    __slots__ = ()

    def __new__(cls, ifd_offset, image):
        [num_entries]     = image.read_at('H', ifd_offset)
        offsets = [ifd_offset + 2 + (12 * i) for i in range(num_entries+1)]

        [next_ifd_offset] = image.read_at('H', offsets.pop())
        entries = [IfdEntry(entry_offset, image) for entry_offset in offsets]

        return super().__new__(cls, image, entries, ifd_offset, num_entries, next_ifd_offset)

    def find_entry(self, name):
        filtered = (entry for entry in self.entries if entry.tag_id == tags[name])
        return next(filtered, None)


class Cr2:
    """
    Load a CR2 file from disk. It is currently read-only.
    Format info: http://lclevy.free.fr/cr2/
    """
    def __init__(self, file_path):
        self.name = file_path
        self._fhandle = open(file_path, "rb")

        try:
            self.header = Header(self)

            self.ifds = [Ifd(16, self)]
            for i in range(3):
                self.ifds.append(Ifd(self.ifds[-1].next_ifd_offset, self))

        except:
            self._fhandle.close()
            raise

    def read_at(self, fmt, offset, endian_flag=None):
        if endian_flag is None:
            endian_flag = self.header.endian_flag

        reader = Struct(endian_flag + fmt)
        self._fhandle.seek(offset)
        data = self._fhandle.read(reader.size)
        return reader.unpack_from(data)

    def __enter__(self):
        return self

    def __exit__(self, type, value, traceback):
        self._fhandle.close()
```

Comment: `Looking further, I got confused as to why you delayed it anyway; value_len never seems to be big so it makes sense just to do it eagerly.` While the code doesn't make this clear, one of the most common usages is to load the actual image data from the file as a large (several MB) byte array (hence the caching). For the other datatypes I could probably go ahead and do a greedy read though. Working through the rest of this and learning / updating as necessary.

Comment: `This pointed out what seems to be a bug: self.parent.fhandle.read(self.value_len) is too few bytes when tag_fmt represents a value of > 1 bytes.` I'm not sure I understood this one either; it seems to work fine. Maybe the confusion arrises because the value in the file (`raw_value`) contains the actual value if it fits in a long, or an offset otherwise. It appears to work anyways, but I may just be misunderstanding you.

Comment: @SamWhited When `tag_fmt` is something like `Q`, it crashed. This didn't occur in the example you gave as it only ever loaded `bytes`.

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean; the CR2 format doesn't set the length except for string and byte arrays; I worked around that in other places, but apparently didn't fix it for the case when the value is an offset to something that's not a string or byte array. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

After sleeping on it last night, I realized that one important area of the code could be refactored and made to be less of a hack. A code review of my own code follows:

Instead of manually adding a character to formatting strings to indicate that the data is stored as a pointer to somewhere else in the file, it would be simpler to just use `struct.calcsize` to check if the data would fit in the alloted space (4 bytes) or if it must be stored somewhere else in the file.

This means that the tag types mapping can have all of the `*`'s removed:

```
# Mapping of tag types to format strings.
tag_types = {
    0x1: 'B', # Unsigned char
    0x2: 's', # String (with ending \0)
    0x3: 'H', # Unsigned short
    0x4: 'L', # Unsigned long
    0x5: 'Q', # Unsigned rational
    0x6: 'b', # Signed char
    0x7: 'p', # Byte sequence
    0x8: 'h', # Signed short
    0x9: 'l', # Signed long
    0xA: 'q', # Signed rational
    0xB: 'f', # Float (IEEE)
    0xC: 'd', # Double (IEEE)
}
```

and the size can be checked manually for everything except strings and bytes:

```
if struct.calcsize(tag_type) > 4 or tag_type == 's' or tag_type == 'p':
```

This is much cleaner than the previous solution of checking the start of the string for the `*` character:

```
if tag_types[self.tag_type][0] == '*':
```

This also means we don't have to double check if we need to remove the first character every time we look up a tag type mapping; we can just use the value straight out of the dict.

Comment: That makes sense. The `if` check looks a bit magic though so I'd suggest putting it in an `is_indirect` or `is_pointer` function.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of requiring a path to a disk file in `def __init__(self, file_path)` it would be more flexible to take a file object. That would let someone to pull an image from a web server or database, wrap the in-memory data in a `StringIO` and hand it to your class.

Comment: Agreed; thanks. I gave it a Wand like API instead so that it can take a file name, a file handle, or a binary blob (see [this commit](https://github.com/campaul/ph.sh/commit/6f1f6932d1ec800f557b0d2ace41e61c5eefe2b9)).